# How to connect to Projector (EPSON EX7220) wirelessly

Tags: 13.10, gnome, epson, projector

I've got my hands on a projector (EPSON EX7220) and I've got it connected to my LAN over Wi-Fi. How might I connect my laptop to it? (Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu Gnome 13.10)

Any help would rock!